# Research Internship: Contacting Faculty or Student?

Tags: research-undergraduate, email, internship

As an undergraduate student aiming for research internships is it better to E-Mail a faculty or a Postdoctoral/Ph.D. student for available research positions?
This is as professors are busy and many times tend to skip through the mail while the Ph.D. student may at least go through it.

Comment: Postdocs aren't students. PhD students may not have the power to give you an internship. Who is advertising the position? You should email them first.